# Checking Network Connectivity before dismissing Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-alertdialog, connectivity

So I have a webview based app. My question is that when `OnReceivedError` is called when there is internet loss, I'd like to

When the user clicks "OK" on the dialog for it to check for connectivity,

- If connectivity is available then dismiss alert and call `web.reload();`
- If there isn't web connectivity (wifi or mobile) then call `finish();`

RESOLVED by the following:

- Changed Alert Dialog Postive button to the following

  ```
  .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {         
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
  ```
- The issue was with the following

  ```
  DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,int paramInt)
  ```

Context context;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.context = this;
  ...
  @Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Webview_Main.this);
        localBuilder2.setTitle(R.string.webview_error_received_title);
        localBuilder2.setMessage(R.string.webview_error_received);
        localBuilder2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        localBuilder2.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                 if(isNetworkAvailible(context))
                 web.reload();
                 else
                 finish();
         }
    };
        localBuilder2.show();
    };
```

isNetworkAvailible Class

```
   public boolean isNetworkAvailible(Context ctx) {

    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (info.isRoaming()) {
        // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to
        // disable internet while roaming, just return false
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting my answer:

```
    Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.context = this; 
    }


@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Webview_Main.this);
        localBuilder2.setTitle(R.string.webview_error_received_title);
        localBuilder2.setMessage(R.string.webview_error_received);
        localBuilder2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        localBuilder2.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,int paramInt) {
                    if(haveInternet(context))
                        web.reload();
                    else
                        finish();
                }
            });
        localBuilder2.show();
    };

public boolean haveInternet(Context ctx) {

    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (info.isRoaming()) {
        // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to
        // disable internet while roaming, just return false
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The error he is pointing out:**The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}** has nothing to do with your answer

Comment: @JackTurky Thanks for the code you wrote, I've attempted it and have no error with the syntax, however when pressing the postive button after network has been restored. It just dismisses the message. doesnt actually call web.reload();

Comment: Sure, please see edits :) In your code is instantiated new DialogInterface.OnClickListener but is not added to the dialog positive button.

Comment: @JackTurky Updated my code per your recommendations was able to find the solution. If your curious to know what resolved it, check my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Since ***this*** keyword in your code is referencing DialogInterface.OnClickListener, then getSystemService is not defined for that type, so you must call getSystemService from a context variable referencing your current activity,for example, like this:

```
context.getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
```

Comment: You're right. However, since WebViewClient is the one that contains onReceivedError, and WebViewClient doesn't derive from Activity or anything like that, (s)he doesn't have context readily available. (S)he'll need to pass that value somehow to the constructor or to the instance.

Comment: @DigCamara I've included the suggested code change for context. However still when pressing the dialog OK button it just dismisses the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing big time, but it seems like you're creating a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, but not assigning it to handle anything.

Change your code:

```
    localBuilder2.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, null);

    localBuilder2.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To check network Availability

In your Activtiy

```
if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(ActvityName.this))// pass activity context
     {
             //do soemthing
     }
```

If you need to check network availability in a non activity class you need to pass the activity context as a parameter to the class constructor and use the activity context.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    MyAnotherClass = new MyAnotherClass(MainActivtity.this); 

}
```

In your MyAnotherClass

```
    Class MyAnotherClass
      {
          Context context;
         public MyAnotherClass(Context activitycontext)
         {
             this.context= activitycontext;
             if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(context))
             {
                     //do something
             }
         }
      }
```

CheckNetwork class

```
public class CheckNetwork {


private static final String TAG = CheckNetwork.class.getSimpleName();



public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
{
    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null)
    {
         Log.d(TAG,"no internet connection");
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(info.isConnected())
        {
            Log.d(TAG," internet connection available...");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG," internet connection");
            return true;
        }

    }
}
}
```